# Multiple Similar (Duplicate) Reports

Tags: looker-studio

I currently created a report that I would like to duplicate 40 times but with a different filter each time. So far I'm afraid this is only possible with a very manual process but I was hoping if someone has a faster solution?

Would it be possible to connect to the DataStudio API (if there is one) and run a script for this?

Also, making a design change can be problematic as it needs to be copied to 40 reports. Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Comment: This question relates to Google-Data-Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this with google support and apparently there is no way yet to do this.

There are currently no API's available to do this nor can you download something similar to an RDL file. Right now the only way is manual duplication and to make adjustments for each report separately.

Answer (score 0):

A report is stored as an RDL file in the file system. Its of XML format. Make a copy of the file in the file system and open the copy using a text editor (I prefer notepad++) and find the parameter. Change the paramater to whatever value you want it to be and save the file under a different name. I would include the parameter name in the report name. If the report as using 'Memphis' I would name the report Sales_Memphis.RDL.

Do this 40 times. Be very careful about not changing the structure of the XML file (Don't change any of the element names or opening and closing symbols(<>). Re-import the file into SSDT report project to verify it is using the correct value.

To import a file into an existing project:
Right click on “Reports” folder and select “Add” then “Existing Item”
Now file browser window will open. 
Find the file  and double click on it.

Ideally you can have a dropdown with all the possible values for users to choose from but I guess that is not appropriate for your needs.

If this is a good solution please check it off as valid solution.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,

Thanks for the very fast reply! This sounds like a great solution. Any chance you can clarify where we can export and import the RDL file?

Comment: Hi Benjamin thanks for providing the additional info and I would definitely check this off as a valid solution. But are we talking about the same Data Studio? I'm talking about Google Data Studio _(I hope I used the correct tag)_ and have no clue where to access the file system.

Comment: You are in a Microsoft forum which involves creating reports of the type SSRS. Everything I twrote was predicated on this. I know nothing about Google's Data Studio.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know how that happened. I used the official tag when asking the question and assumed it would be routed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [custom bookmarking](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7664330?hl=en). It sounds like it might be able to address the problem you're expressing. This way you would only have one report, but the links you would share would automatically apply the correct filter value.